# Load and run an OSGi class in a bundle from a C++ application using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, osgi, unreal-engine4

I am trying to call some Java code in an OSGi bundle from a C++ application (an UE4 game to be precise).

```
/* Finding and calling the createJVM function. */
    typedef jint(JNICALL *createJVMfunction)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
    createJVMfunction createJVM = (createJVMfunction)GetProcAddress(jvmDll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    jint res = createJVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res == JNI_OK)
    {
        jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("org/example/simulation/panel/panelsimulation");

        if (dataClass == nullptr) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

However, It fails on the FindClass JNI method. Most likely due the global classpath with it's own classloader conflicting with OSGI's own bundle classloaders. OSGI doesn't use the global classpath classloader. DataClass stays NULL and thus exits the code.

```
#define classPath   "-Djava.class.path=C:/Eclipse workspace/app/example.simulation.panel/generated/example.simulation.panel.jar"
```

What would be a solution for this? Previous answers suggest a helper class exposing the bundle including it's own classloader and calling that method from C++. i'm not sure how to approach this and if it's the best solution.

**Edit:** I've found some extra info in regards to a helper class. Exposing the class through exposing the bundle. How would one fill in "bundle bundle =" and would this be a correct way of approach? How would one fill Bundle Bundle?

```
 public static Class<?> getNativeClass() {
// Find bundle from system bundle context.
Bundle bundle = ... // details left out.

return bundle.loadClass("org.example.Native");
```